# Bug in Mathematica 12 neural networks?

Tags: neural-networks

I recently downloaded Mathematica 12, and I'm experiencing a curious failure in neural networks that had earlier worked. This failure I will demonstrate with the NN in "Classifying Data with Neural Networks—Wolfram Language Documentation" https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NeuralNetworksClassification.html#280210622

Everything in that page works until this line:

```
results = NetTrain[net, trainingData, All]
```

It gives $Failed with this message:

> NetTrain::encgenfail2: Could not encode one or more inputs for port
>   "Output": supplied data was a length-64 vector of real numbers, but
>   expected a class. The invalid inputs had indices
>   {504,841,210,1645,1285,165,956,691,940,613,1426,297,1560,754,650,1725,1662,44,831,1160,1262,1289,1060,886,1147,1578,1342,424,1176,749,1664,1030,211,1011,121,475,237,1120,79,1399,287,1791,293,214,271,222,761,1511,960,1154,<<14>>}.

What is going wrong? A very similar NN worked in version 11.

ETA: detailed version info:

Mma 12.0.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) running on macOS Mojave 10.14.4

The complete code, from that link:

```
makeCluster[class_, \[Mu]_, \[Rho]_] := 
  RandomVariate[
    MultinormalDistribution[\[Mu], {{1, 2 \[Rho]}, {2 \[Rho], 4}}], 
    600] -> class; clusters = 
  makeCluster @@@ {{Red, {1.5, 1.5}, -.2}, {Green, {-1.5, 
      1}, .1}, {Blue, {0, -2.5}, .8}}; trainingData = Flatten[Thread /@ clusters]

net = NetChain[{LinearLayer[30], ElementwiseLayer[Ramp], 
   LinearLayer[3], SoftmaxLayer[]}, "Input" -> {2}, 
  "Output" -> NetDecoder[{"Class", {Red, Green, Blue}}]]

results = NetTrain[net, trainingData, All]
```

Comment: It works for me on Win 10.

Comment: Works for me on Windows 10 32 bit.

Comment: Can you post a standalone example which reproduces this issue for you in a fresh, clean kernel session?

Comment: Does `PacletSiteUpdate/@PacletSites[]; PacletUpdate["NeuralNetworks"]` and then restarting the kernel help?

Comment: I attempted to update the NN code as described by Stefan R, but it gave the same kind of failure. I checked with PacletInformation["NeuralNetwork"], and it is at version 12.0.8

Comment: Can you try to run this on a fresh kernel?
`NeuralNetworks\`Private\`ReinitializeNeuralNetworks[];
DeleteDirectory[#, DeleteContents -> True] & /@ FileNames[
   FileNameJoin@{"*", #} & /@ {"NeuralNetworks*", "MXNetLink*"},
   FileNameJoin@{$CacheBaseDirectory, "PacletCachedData"}
   ];`
Then `Quit` and try again. This will delete internal definitions for the neural net framework that we cache locally to speed up loading times. Maybe those local files got corrupted.

Comment: I tried it, and it worked. Wolfram's demo neural network seems to be working properly again. I tried the NN that I was working on, and it also works. Thanx.

Comment: I encounter the same error message during evaluation of Classify[] but only on large datasets and without specified method: [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/197520/bug-in-the-classification-optimization-algorithm-for-large-data-sets)

Answer (score 6):

Since the answer that solved the problem was posted in a comment by Matteo Salvarezza, I will reproduce it here as an answer for the convenience of anyone else running into this (note that this will quit your kernel, so only run it after saving any variable definitions you may want to hang on to):

```
NeuralNetworks`Private`ReinitializeNeuralNetworks[];
DeleteDirectory[#, DeleteContents -> True] & /@ FileNames[
   FileNameJoin @ {"*", #} & /@ {"NeuralNetworks*", "MXNetLink*"},
   FileNameJoin @ {$CacheBaseDirectory, "PacletCachedData"}
 ];
Quit
```

This will delete internal definitions for the neural net framework that we cache locally to speed up loading times. These local files could have been corrupted if you have this problem.

Another line that's useful to keep in mind when you're having trouble with neural networks:

```
PacletUpdate["NeuralNetworks"]
```